# Spring WebApplicationInitializer could not be found

Tags: java, spring

I am developing Spring WS which was working fine, it looks like i messed something up because now all i get is HTTP 404 error with console:

```
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
lis 29, 2012 1:49:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Anyone have an idea what could be wrong? or where i should start checking? because i watched almost every xml and it looks ok.

Comment: The WebApplicationInitializer is irrelevant I think.  The container has been told to load the JSF auto-configure framework.  Do you have conflicting JSF jar files in your war or in the container?

Comment: only JSF i have are:`<dependency><br>
       <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId><br>
       <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId><br>
       <version>2.1.0-b11</version><br>
       <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency><br>
       <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId><br>
       <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId><br>
       <version>2.1.0-b11</version><br>
       <scope>compile</scope><br>
      </dependency>`

Comment: OK, then you *are* using JSF. If you don't need that dependency you can remove it, or mark it as scope=provided (since Tomcat appears to have it already, but a conflicting version).

Comment: I kind of figured this out but im not quite sure what is going on. If i remove javaee-api.jar from my pom.xml it works great. But i have to have this jar on my classpath in order to be able to use JPA any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd narrow your Java EE dependencies to just JPA - you don't need the whole of the javaee-api.jar for that.  I would expect your JPA provider to pull in that dependency for you transitively (Hibernate does, or did last time I used it, for instance).  That way there won't be a conflict between Tomcat's own libraries and those in your app.

Comment: Thank You Dave ! it solved my issue javax.persistence was enough!